# Using awesome_nested_set, how to define a has_many relation with all the descendants as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, awesome-nested-set

I have a simple product and category models along with product_category models that establishes presence in the product category tree.

Product is always placed to the deepest possible categories.

It is intended to call

```
root_category = Category.find(1)
root_category.products
```

and basically get all products that have a category assigned.

What happens is that I can only get products from one of the descendant category if said category is selected instead of `root_category` using

```
category.self_and_descendants.includes(:products)
```

How can I make it that I call `category.products` that does basically the above?

```
== app/models/product.rb ==
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :product_categories
end

== app/models/product_category.rb ==
class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end

== app/models/category.rb ==
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :products, through: :product_categories
end
```